# How to format a value from KG's to t with Twig and Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

I am building a system that is dealing with weights of materials that a company collects. Because of the sheer number of materials collected, the client wishes to have the weights displayed in tonnes (t) and not in kilograms (kg).

However, the data that is entered via an csv contains all of the materials in separate rows, all recorded in KG. I can add all of the KG's together for all the materials to be displayed, but I'm not sure how I can format the value from KG to t.

For example, 10 materials are displayed all weighing 100KG's each. This has a total of 1,000KG, but I want to display it in tonnes which would be either 1t or 1.0t.

Using twig and Symfony2, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to write an extension for Twig, it's easy and this way you can reuse it everywhere.

[How to write a custom Twig Extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html)

After the extension you can write it like:

```
{{ KG|ton_format }}
```

Comment: This made more sense so I used this method. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

you could simply do this in symfony/php

if you need to round the result use http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.round.php

```
  $items = $fooRepository->findYourStuff();
  $overallWeight=0;     
  for($items as $item){
      $overallWeight += $item->getWeightInKilo();
  }
  $metricTons= $overallWeight/1000;
```

you could do the same in twig but i would keep logic away from view.

even better would be to add a method to your entityClass like :

```
 public function getWeightInTons(){
     return ( $this->getWeightInKilos() / 1000 );
 }
```

then in twig you could call

```
{{ item.getWeightInTons }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Plus the answers below you can also try:

```
{% set total = 0 %}
{% for item in myStuff %}
   {% set total = total + item.getWeight %}
{% endfor %}
<span>Total: </span>{{ (total/1000)|round(2, 'floor') }}
```

*Using floor or ceil and amount of precision are up to you*

Answer (score 0):

If you have the total weight in kilograms set to a variable, you can also use the [`number_format`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/number_format.html) and [`format`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/format.html) filters:

```
{% set weight_in_kilos = 24450 %}

{{ (weight_in_kilos/1000)|number_format(1) }}t
{{ '%.1ft'|format(weight_in_kilos/1000) }}
```

The above prints:

```
24.5t
24.4t
```

Notice how the two filters handle rounding differently: `number_format` rounds mathematically whereas `format` just cuts the output to have the specified amount of decimals.